# Store nested object from .net to a SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server

I build an object in vb.net where I store data from JSON file that I get from a RESTApi. The object is nested and looks like this:

```
Public Class FullData
    Public Property userID As ULong
    Public Property data As List(Of String)
End Class

Public Class GeneralInfo
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property data As List(Of FullData)
End Class
```

Now I want to store these data into a sql database and I am not sure what technique is appropriate and easy to implement.

Could someone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two tables with an extra `GeneralInfoId` col on `FullData` to provide the relationship.

As a side note, you would be wise to be consistent with your Id fields. You have one long and one int.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will change the datatype, this is a good note. Could you give me a hint how the connection should look like? I have heard about Entity Framework. Should I use this?

Comment: no you should not use EF. try https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlclient